# ulimit PICKLE: "Operation not permitted" and "Command not found"

Tags: bash, fedora, sudo, limit

I'm trying to increase the maximum number of open files for the current user

```
> ulimit -n
1024
```

I attempt to increase and fail as follows

```
> ulimit -n 4096
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

So I do the natural thing and try to run with temp permission, but fail

```
> sudo ulimit -n 4096
sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

**Questions**

1. How to increase ulimit?
2. Why is this happening?

*Using Fedora 14*

Comment: Reponse to deleted comment: `ulimit 4096` doesn't work. I think `-n` is correct. As a proof of concept it works if I first `sudo su - root` (but only changes for root).

Comment: What is PICKLE? SU http://superuser.com/questions/79717/bash-ulimit-core-file-size-cannot-modify-limit-operation-not-permitted/

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundown

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ulimit` is a shell built-in, not an external command. It needs to be built in because it acts on the shell process itself, like `cd`: the limits, like the current directory, are a property of that particular process.

`sudo bash -c 'ulimit -n 4096'` would work, but it would change the limit for the bash process invoked by `sudo` only, which would not help you.

There are two values for each limit: the hard limit and the soft limit. Only root can raise the hard limit; anyone can lower the hard limit, and the soft limit can be modified in either direction with the only constraint that it cannot be higher than the hard limit. The soft limit is the actual value that matters.

Therefore you need to arrange that all your processes have a hard limit for open files of at least 4096. You can keep the soft limit at 1024. Before launching that process that requires a lot of files, raise the soft limit. In `/etc/security/limits.conf`, add the lines

```
paislee hard nofile 4096
paislee soft nofile 1024
```

where `paislee` is the name of the user you want to run your process as. In the shell that launches the process for which you want a higher limit, run

```
ulimit -Sn unlimited
```

to raise the soft limit to the hard limit.

Comment: Alternatives to `sudo bash -c` are `sudo -i` which starts a login shell and `sudo -s` whcih starts a shell. The same limitations apply but this might be useful in other circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask some related questions? The other reply and post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483998/156458 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238413/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169035/674 all recommended using  `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"`. But  both `ulimit -c 1024` and `exec su $LOGNAME"`  only affects the shell created by `sudo`, so what is the purpose of the command? `exec su $LOGNAME"` also doesn't do anything meaningful to make use of the changed limit. I am very confused and wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: Please note that `ulimit -Sn unlimited` does not work on most shells. The right method is to call `ulimit -a` and then call `ulimit -n <number>` where <number is the hard limit (the right column).

Answer (score 3):

open the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add the line `<user> soft nofile <value>`. for using `ulimit` change to root user and try the same.